# In a shell script, does the command on line 2 waits for the command on line 1 to be finished?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, command

The title explains it all. I wish to know if a command written in a shell script waits for the precedent command to be over. If yes, is there a way to force the simultaneous execution of commands in a shell script ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The shell finishes each command before starting the next - else you could never assume anything you itemised before had been done, so you couldn't create a file and then read it, for example. If you want it to continue with second command before the first one is finished, add `&` after the first command and it will execute in the background. Get started with `bash` by reading this https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you very much for your answer, that was exactly what i needed to know !

Comment: @Armali Yes, you're right, I made a mistake ;)